# Use sharepoint One Drive as a file share to run scripts from for powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, onedrive

How would I use Use sharepoint One Drive as a file share to run scripts from for powershell.  Since I had to decommission my file share and move to one drive.

Utilized the subst P:\users\admin\onedrive folder which went well.   Now I need to get the scripts to point to this file share in order to run the powershell properly.